# custom element pre-upgrade usage catch when overriding properties

Tags: javascript, dom, custom-element

I've recently came across the following situation and looking for an advice / elegant solution of pretty tricky misbehave, IMHO.

Let's assume that I've created the following custom element definition in file `bible-reference.js`:

```
class BibleReference extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    get value() { return this._value; }
    set value(newValue) { this._value = newValue; }
}

customElements.define('bible-reference', BibleReference);
```

We've defined our new element, and we have a `value` property getter/setter to interact with this element's value. Pay attention, that the getter/setter will be found on the element's `prototype` object, which is okay in itself, to be sure.

Now, let's review the following HTML layout that happened to be in my case:

```
<bible-reference id='elem-1'></bible-reference>
<script src="starter.js"></script>
<script src="bible-reference.js"></bible-reference>
```

The trick is in that `starter.js` content. If this script contains code below, things get broken:

```
let br = document.getElementById('elem-1');
br.value = 'some value';
```

The `value` is set on the **non-upgraded** yet element, therefore it is not the getter/setter that are being invoked, but just a new property is added to the element. Having this property set on the object itself, even after the upgrade is done the `value`'s **getter/setter are not accessible** for **this** element instance anymore, since there is an (overriding) `value` property available before getting to the prototype.

I've solved it meanwhile by adding `delete this.value;` to the constructor, but... what a hack!

Any insights appreciated.

Comment: it's a hack but it's a good and legitimate one so where's the problem? you could just add a condition before deleting the property and maybe copying the `value`'s value to `this._value`

Comment: i'm considering any unexpected (it happened to me after working with CE for quite a while now, maybe i've not been sharp enough this time :) and unpredictable (think of another contributor adding some script in the app's init cycle not even being aware of potential to break things) - as something bad in essence and must be improved

Comment: ah, and i think that adding such a `delete` logic for any custom property, just  in case, is ridiculous but would be inescapable, since the properties may be accessed even by third/second party, as it happened to me with my own MVVC lib in this case

Answer (score 2):

Another way to handle the issue would be to define the `value` property in the closure of the `constructor()`.

```html
<bible-reference id='elem-1'></bible-reference>
<script>
  let br = document.getElementById('elem-1');
  br.value = 'Genesis 1:1';

  class BibleReference extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super()
      var _value = this.value
      Reflect.defineProperty(this, 'value', {
        get: () => _value,
        set: newValue => _value = newValue        
      })
    }
  }
  customElements.define('bible-reference', BibleReference);
  
  console.log(br.value)
</script>
```

But I guess you'll say it's a bad hack ;-) Anyway I'd prefer your `delete` solution.

Comment: well, it is definitely not the way ES class properties are meant to be defined, but actually i may think that this one is better than `delete` - at least it is clear what's going on here, while for an untrained eye the `delete` may look at least strange, and +1 for the private `_value` which is impossible in other way in the classes syntax